# Hall effect current transducer schematic diagram

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, hall-effect

What is the function of the amplifier **2** in the below circuit diagram?
[image]

HCT-0016 Hall Effect Split-Core Current Transducer: https://www.magnelab.com/products/hall-effect-split-core-current-transducer-hct-0010/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have given no context or credit for the schematic (which is in violation of site policy so you should fix that) but it looks like a [Hall-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect#:~:text=The%20Hall%20effect%20is%20the,by%20Edwin%20Hall%20in%201879.) based current sensor.

> The Hall effect is the production of a voltage difference (the Hall voltage) across an electrical conductor, transverse to an electric current in the conductor and to an applied magnetic field perpendicular to the current. It was discovered by Edwin Hall in 1879.

Sensors based on the Hall-effect run a controlled current through the sensor which is placed in the magnetic field to be measured. The voltage across the sensor is then amplified to give a signal proportional to the magnetic field strength.

[image]

*Figure 1. A magnified view of the schematic.*

1. The output amplifier.
2. The reference current amplifier with offset adjustment potentiometer.
3. The sensor.
4. The magnetic core (suggesting a torroidal current sensor).
5. The primary winding(s) which pass through the magnetic circuit.
6. Full-scale adjustment. (This is in the amplifier feedback circuit and adjusts the gain.)

Comment: Do the terminals of the offset adjustment potentiometer are also connected to the 15 V?

Comment: We don't know. The fact that they haven't shown it connected to +15 V suggests that it's more complicated than that. The link in your question just brings me to the company's home page rather than the datasheet (pdf).

Comment: There is no datasheet of the sensor. They only provided the schematic diagram and the current-voltage graph of the sensor.